# InStr and InStrRev not returning positions to Mid properly

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub nosaukuma_splits()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim p

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("splits_name")
    RowCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To RowCount
        vertiba = ws.Cells(i, 2)
        pzime = InStr(vertiba, " -")
        ozime = InStrRev(vertiba, "- ")

        ws.Cells(i, 3) = Mid(vertiba, 1, pzime)
    Next i

    For i = 1 To RowCount
        vertiba = ws.Cells(i, 2)
        pzime = InStr(vertiba, " -")
        ozime = InStrRev(vertiba, "- ")

        ws.Cells(i, 4) = Mid(vertiba, pzime, ozime - pzime)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Why my code doesn't execute on row 23? what could be the reason?

Cell text looks like `(1text) - (2text) - (3text)`

I need to get `(1text)` and `(2text)` in separated cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the VBA [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to separate the text values into a variant array and then return the elements of the array you want back to the worksheet.

```
Sub nosaukuma_splits()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, rc As Long, vTXTs As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("splits_name")

    With ws
        rc = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To rc
            vTXTs = Split(.Cells(i, 2).Value2, " - ")
            .Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 2) = Array(vTXTs(0), vTXTs(1))
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

As far as your original code is concerned, you were not properly compensating for the length of the delimiter (e.g. either "- " or " -") when determining the starting point and length in the [Mid function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
Sub nosaukuma_splits_pirmais()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, rc As Long, pzime As Long, ozime As Long, vertiba As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("splits_name")
    rc = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To rc
        vertiba = ws.Cells(i, 2)
        pzime = InStr(1, vertiba, " -")
        ozime = InStr(pzime, vertiba, "- ")
        ws.Cells(i, 3) = Trim(Mid(vertiba, 1, pzime))
    Next i

    For i = 1 To rc
        vertiba = ws.Cells(i, 2)
        pzime = InStr(1, vertiba, " -") + 2
        ozime = InStr(pzime + 1, vertiba, "- ")
        ws.Cells(i, 4) = Trim(Mid(vertiba, pzime, ozime - pzime))
    Next i

End Sub
```

I've abandoned the [InStrRev function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2ekk41a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and used the position of hte first delimiter to start the search for the position of the second with [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

There also seemed to be some leading/trailing spaces left over in the result(s) put back into the worksheet so I added a [Trim function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9wz3dez%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to take care of those.

Comment: Approved. Thank you for helping me! I left those spaces " -" or "- " there, because there are cells, which have text-text, and i can't take them as seperator.

Answer (score 0):

```
ozime = InStrRev(vertiba, "- ")
```

Returns the position of "- " calculated from the end of the vertiba string.

You should calculate the position from the beginning of the string to get the length of the substring between the two dashes.

Something like:
    ws.Cells(i, 4) = Mid(vertiba, pzime, Len(vertiba) - ozime - pzime)

Comment: I believe you will find that [InStrRev function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2ekk41a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) actually returns the position from the *beginning* of the string, not from the end as you might expect. In other words, it is just returning the position of the last occurrence from the string, not the position counted backwards from the end of the string. `InstrRev("(1text) - (2text) - (3text)", " - ")` returns 18, not 7.